# Errors deploying Go Revel app on Heroku using buildpack

Tags: heroku, go, buildpack, revel

I'm trying to use Go and Revel on Heroku using this buildpack https://github.com/robfig/heroku-buildpack-go-revel but it doesn't seem to work:

I'm getting an error trying to use the basic revel helloworld example.

```
$ go get github.com/robfig/helloworld
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/robfig/helloworld
$ echo "github.com/robfig/helloworld" > .godir
$ git add .godir
$ git commit -a -m ".godir"
$  heroku create -b https://github.com/robfig/heroku-buildpack-go-revel.git
$ git push heroku master

Counting objects: 34, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
Writing objects: 100% (34/34), 57.41 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 34 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Revel app detected
-----> Installing Go 1.1.2... done
       Installing Virtualenv... done
       Installing Mercurial... done
       Installing Bazaar... done
-----> Running: go get -tags heroku ./...
mv: cannot stat `/tmp/build_86bd3433-7925-4ae9-b4bf-f5466525aef1/.go/bin/*': No such file or directory

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Revel app

To git@heroku.com:peaceful-hamlet-6152.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:peaceful-hamlet-6152.git'
```

Answer (score 3):

I forked the heroku-buildpack-go-revel and was able to fix the error that was moving the non-existent directory (I changed it to conditionally move it).

Fixed buildpack:

- https://github.com/dougnukem/heroku-buildpack-go-revel/commit/d0d17027b981248062fa46098ce3c2e9b8559a76

I was then able to deploy a helloworld revel app to heroku:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
mkdir $GOPATH
go get github.com/dougnukem/revel-helloworld
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/dougnukem/revel-helloworld
heroku create
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/dougnukem/heroku-buildpack-go-revel.git
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

I submitted a pull request with that fix:

- https://github.com/robfig/heroku-buildpack-go-revel/pull/4